# Call a modal from the Rails controller once a form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying calling a modal from the controller once a form is submitted and the customer is created. I tried browsing around but I didn't find an answer.

Here is my controller:

```
def create
   @customer = Customer.new(packets_params)

   respond_to do |format|
    if @customer.save
      UserMailer.with(customer: @customer).welcome_email.deliver
           
      format.html { redirect_to(new_customer_path) }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
    end
  end
end
```

can you please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a modal"? You're rendering HTML; if you want something to happen on the client side then you'd need to render something into the HTML that the page's JS can act on after load.

Comment: which model you are talking about?, I can see you are already calling `Customer` model in your code

Comment: Paste the complete controller code

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma I think OP means`modal` probably as a front end component like a [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/), and not `model` like a `ActiveRecord` data type model.

Comment: @lacostenycoder: I suspect the model because he is using `packet_params`, so I want to confirm that this method is present or not because if we are creating customer then the method name for permitting parameters should be `customer_params`, 
but yes, your point is also valid

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to avoid any front-end rendering, you could return a JSON response containing the HTML for a modal you defined inside an `erb` file:

```
def create
   @customer = Customer.new(packets_params)

    if @customer.save
      UserMailer.with(customer: @customer).welcome_email.deliver

      render(
        modal: render_to_string('welcome_modal.html.erb'),
        status: :created
      )
    else
      render(
        errors: @customer.errors
        status: :bad_request
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Then your modal template might look like:

```
# app/views/mycontroller/_welcome_modal.html.erb
<div class="modal welcome-modal" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog">
  <h1> Welcome! </h1>
</div>
```

Make sure your template file lives in the standard directory structure required for views, and is prefixed with `_` to denote it being a partial.

On the frontend side, you'd make the request as an AJAX call and either render the modal to the screen or handle the errors returned:

```
// some JS file - implementation is proof of concept and not clean

$('form').on('submit', function () {
  var data = $('form').serialize();
  $.post('/customer', data)
    .done(function (res) { /* render modal */ }
    .error(function (error) { /* handle errors */ }

});
```